# Card borderOnForeground isn't working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
Card(
  color: Colors.blue,
  borderOnForeground: false, // doesn't do anything on true also
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300)),
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    color: Color(0x30FF0C5C),
    child: Text(
      "|||||||",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Docs say:**

> borderOnForeground: Whether to paint the [shape] border in front of the [child].
>   The default value is true. If false, the border will be painted behind the [child].

**Output:**

[image]

**Issue:**

I want the white vertical lines to be inside the blue circle when by default (when `borderOnForeground: true`) but it doesn't do that, neither it does on setting it to `false`. What `borderOnForeground` actually does then?

**NOTE:**

I know there are many ways of achieving what I asked using `ClipRRect`, `ClipOval` etc. I am not looking for those solutions, I just want to know what `borderOnForeground` does?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have no border (like in CSS) and that's why `true` and `false` look the same. To see the difference, add a thick border:

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(300.0),
  ),
  side: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 20.0,
  ),
),
```

and if you set `borderOnForeground: false` the part of the Card's child that was under the red border will now be above it.